# C++: Singleton Class Design (Error: unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static, singleton, linker-errors

I'm implementing a singleton class design for a C++ project on Visual Studio. It was based on this [GitHub code sample](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098119). Logic-wise, my code seems correct, but there's an error from my compiler. Does anyone know what's wrong?

I have several singleton classes. Here's a code sample for one of them.

**AccountBG.h**

```
#ifndef ACCOUNTBG_H
#define ACCOUNTBG_H

#include "Lecturer.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Type.h"

class AccountBG
{
public:
   static AccountBG* getInstance();
   // GET Methods
   Lecturer* getLecturer();
   Student* getStudent();
   // SET Methods
   void setLecturer(int, string);
   void setStudent(int, string);
private:
   // Singleton class instance
   static AccountBG* instance;
   AccountBG(); // Private constructor to prevent instancing.
   Lecturer *lecturer;
   Student *student;
};

#endif // !ACCOUNTBG_H
```

**AccountBG.cpp**

```
#include "AccountBG.h"
// Null, because instance will be initialized on demand.
AccountBG* AccountBG::instance = 0;

AccountBG* AccountBG::getInstance() {
    if (instance == 0) {
        instance = new AccountBG();
    }
    return instance;
}

// GET Methods
Lecturer* AccountBG::getLecturer() {
    return this->lecturer;
}

Student* AccountBG::getStudent() {
    return this->student;
}

// SET Methods
void AccountBG::setLecturer(int id, string username) {
    this->lecturer = new Lecturer();
    this->lecturer->setID(id);
    this->lecturer->setUsername(username);
    this->lecturer->setType("Lecturer");
}

void AccountBG::setStudent(int id, string username) {
    this->student = new Student();
    this->student->setID(id);
    this->student->setUsername(username);
    this->student->setType("Student");
}
```

**Screenshot of Compiler Errors**

[Errors as seen on VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqKb8.png)

Comment: If you create an instance of the class (which you do in `getInstance`) you need a constructor. You don't have a constructor *defined*, only *declared*.

Comment: Well, is if this is all the AccountBG code, then the error about the missing constructor is certainly valid. There is none provided; only declared in the class decl. If you declared it, *write it*.

Comment: Aside missing the constructor definition (learn to read and interpret compiler errors, it will save you a lot of time in the future!), you are also abusing pointers. It may be better to learn about smart pointers, std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr as well as avoid using pointers when not strictly needed, and use references instead.

Comment: @WhozCraig Do you mean to implement the private constructor, AccountBG()?

Comment: @Print-ABC Yes, because you ARE calling it inside AccountBG::getInstance(), thus the compiler needs it to be implemented.
And please be safe, in the default constructor DO initialize pointers members to nullptr.

Comment: @roalz Okay. Will give it a shot when I get home. Thanks :)

Comment: @Print-ABC Also DO NOT use 0 as "null", use nullptr instead!

Answer (score 1):

*unresolved external symbol* usually caused by calling a declared, but un-implemented function.

In your case, you don't implement constructor for `AccountBG`, only declared.

Possible same problem for other functions:

```
MarkingData::instance()
Quiz::Quiz()
QuizTracker::QuizTracker()
```

Add implementation to these functions may solve your problem.

Comment: How do you know it's the same problem for other unresolved symbols? the OP didn't include enough code to be sure :-)

Comment: @roalz Indeed it is *possible* to be caused by other problem. :-) Updated my answer to add a *possible* in it.

Comment: @MartinZhai Yo. Thanks for answering. Do you mean to just implement the private constructor, AccountBG(), and it'll be okay?

Comment: @Print-ABC I think it should be OK after you implement those functions. Just give a try and we'll be sure.

Comment: @MartinZhai WIll do later when I get home. Thanks! :)